# How find and select tag in html with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

This part of text from get response http://youtube.com/.
How parse response and get icon with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vflz7uhzw.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
      <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_32-vfl8NGn4k.png" sizes="32x32">
      <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_48-vfl1s0rGh.png" sizes="48x48">
      <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_96-vfldSA3ca.png" sizes="96x96">
      <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_144-vflWmzoXw.png" sizes="144x144">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get icon"? You wnat to get the tags with the property rel equals to "icon"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all href values:

```
List<String> href = new ArrayList<>();
// Considering that text is a String variable that contains the html
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(text);
for (Element element : document.select("link")) {
    href.add(element.attr("href"));
}
// In this point the list href will have all the links
```

In the case you need to select only the link with a specific rel attribute you could switch "link" by:

```
"link[rel~=\"icon\"]" //could have 1 or more rel values
"link[rel=\"icon\"]" //rel equals to icon
```

Comment: The links in the example are protocol relative (ie they start with `//`). To get absolute links replace `element.attr("href")` with `element.absUrl("href")`.